# Accessing and adding shared contacts Sharepoint server

Tags: php, sharepoint

Today i am faced with a problem that the company i work for is going to try to centralize their global sales team`s contacts to a SharePoint server.

There are 2 parts to my question,

Firstly is there a web server or API i can use to programatically add contacts which i have stored on a local database to the sharepoint shared contacts list?

Secondly is there a web service which i can plug into to do the reverse? basically the plan is one the sales team have been using it for a while they would like a way in which we can use that contact information for analytics.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you mean by the *sharepoint shared contacts list*? Is it a SharePoint list you created?

Comment: i am guessing so, the admin made it, i personally have never had much to do with sharepoint so its a first for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint has numerous Web services. The `Lists` Web service will probably the one you need ([2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists_methods%28v=office.12%29.aspx), [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists_methods.aspx)). Start with the `GetListItems` and `UpdateListItems` methods.

Additionally, SharePoint 2010 supports a [JavaScript client object model](http://www.avanadeblog.com/sharepointasg/2011/05/client-object-model-introduction-part-1-reading-list-items.html).